# Excel VBA function error

Tags: excel

I write this code in  the module:

```
Public Function first()
If (x + 1 < 0) Or (1 - 2 * Sin(x) < 0) Or Sqr(1 - 2 * Sin(x)) = 0 Then
first = "error"
Else
first = Sqr(x + 1) / Sqr(1 - 2 * Sin(x))
End If
End Function
```

It gives an error with certain values:

[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: Why not describe what the problem is? What are these "certain values"? Also -- what is `x`? It is odd that you are not *passing* `x` as a parameter. Global variables are more often than not a design flaw.

Comment: When `Sin(x)` is 0.5 (30 degrees...?) then `Sqr(1 - 2 * Sin(x))` is zero and you cannot divide by zero.

Comment: In context, `x` *must* be the parameter of the function. It looks like they translated it from Lithuanian (?) (where "pirma" means "first") and probably just dropped the `x` from the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that your intention is to evaluate `Sin(x)` where `x` is measured in *degrees* (if for no other reason than that evaluating at radians which are whole numbers other than `0` is quite rare), but the function `Sin(x)` works with radians. You can use the function `Randians()` to fix this:

```
Public Function first(ByVal x As Double) As Double
    x = Application.Radians(x)
    If (x + 1 < 0) Or (1 - 2 * Sin(x) < 0) Or Sqr(1 - 2 * Sin(x)) = 0 Then
        first = "error"
    Else
        first = Sqr(x + 1) / Sqr(1 - 2 * Sin(x))
    End If
End Function
```

Then, for example, `first(7)` evaluates to `1.218130941`.

Answer (score 0):

When **x** is **7**, `Sin(x)` is equal to **0.656986598718789**.

When you plug this into the formula `1 - 2 * Sin(x)`, you get **-0.313973197437578**.

You cannot take the square root (i.e. `Sqr(...)`) of a negative number. I would suggest adding `Abs(...)` as a wrapper to guarantee a positive number but I have no idea what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.